# nested table overflowing outer parent table

Tags: html, css

The nested table i created is as

```
<table border="0" width="750" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr align="center">
 <td width="530">
     <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="530">
         <tr>
             <td>
               <tr>
                        <td width="14"></td>
                        <td width="177">
                            <p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-align: left; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">Expand Your Reach</p>
                            <ul style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; list-style-image:url(http://demo.frostmiller.com/sss104/images/bullet.jpg);text-align:left; margin-left: 25px; padding:0; list-style-position:outside;">
                                <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
                                <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
                                <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
                            </ul>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td width="29"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <hr width="220" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="14"></td>
                        <td width="177" align="left">
                            <p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-align: left;">Contact Info</p>
                            <p style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 2cm;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer  .</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="29"></td>
                    </tr>
                 </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
          <td width="220">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, the nesting of the inner table of width 530 leads to overflow of the border of the outer table.

Comment: If I paste that code into a blank html-file, I can't reproduce the error you described (using Chromium and Opera). Check any additional CSS-settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add padding to the container TD tag of inner Table i.e. style="padding: 10px;"

Answer (score 3):

In the inner table, you can set the css property `table-layout:fixed`. See if it solves your problem.